# How to fetch the entire table data and show them in the user interface in django using templates

Tags: python, html, css, django, templates

I have defined a model called "Files" having fields as Id(auto genrated) and file_name.I want to fetch all the file names from the database and show them as a list on the UI.I am developing a django project.
I have added a read_files.html in the templates folder.

```
{% extends "home/base.html" %}
{% block title %}title{% endblock %}
{% block subtitle %}Read File{% endblock %}
<body>
    <ul>
        {% for f in Files %}
        <li>{{ f.name }}</li>
        {% empty %}
        <li>Sorry, no files present in this list.</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
{% endblock %}'
```

But i am not able to see the correct results. Either it gives error
'Invalid block tag: 'endblock'' or 'incorrectly spelled text string endfor'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are missing a block opening tag after the subtitle block:

I added a {% block content %} tag (change "content" for the right block name

```
{% extends "home/base.html" %}
{% block title %}title{% endblock %}
{% block subtitle %}Read File{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<body>
<ul>
{% for f in Files %}
<li>{{ f.name }}</li>
{% empty %}
<li>Sorry, no files present in this list.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

also don't add extra characters after you finish a block if you are extending a template